# In how many ways can five prizes be distributed to three groups if at least one person from group C must receive an award?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I need help with the following problem:
There are 3 groups of people: Group A of 4 people, Group B of 5 people, Group C of 6 people. In how many ways can these people receive 5 identical rewards if...

1. At least one person from group C must receive a reward.
2. At least one person from each group must receive a reward, but no more then 2 people from one group.

Comment: The edit messes the question.First sub question was supposed to focused on Group A

Comment: @harambe I know, I initially typed it wrong.

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive answers that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  For 1, compute the ways to hand out the five rewards and subtract those which don't give any to the group A people.  For 2, the rewards need to be distributed $2+2+1$ among the three groups in some order.  Condition on the group to get $1$ and then pick the people to get the rewards.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the hint for 2?

Comment: If the $1$ goes to group $A$, there are four ways to pick who gets it, times how many ways to pick the two in $B$, times how many ways to pick the two in $C$.  Now do $B$ and $C$ as getting $1$ and add